# How can I import the values of a variable in a csv file, in python?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I need to import the values of the variables sum and diff into my test.csv file, how can I do that? I leave my code below:

```
x=3
y=5
z=2
sum=x + y + 5
diff= x-y-5

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    thewriter.writerow(['sum', 'diff'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use sum as a variable name in Python as it is the name for a builtin function. Also quotes define a string and don't refer to a variable.

```
dif = 10
print('dif')
print(dif)
```

outputs:

```
dif
10
```

your code would look like

```
import csv

x=3
y=5
z=2
sum_x_y=x + y + 5
diff= x-y-5

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)
    thewriter.writerow(["sum_x_y", "diff"])
    thewriter.writerow([sum_x_y, diff])
```

Comment: It is possible that the OP wanted the csv file to have a header row of `sum, diff` with the actual data as the second row and that's why the OP was writing out literal strings. This is based on my assumption that the OP knows the difference between `diff` and `'diff'`.

Comment: ah yes might be possible, i updated my answer according to this

Comment: Of course. there is no reason why the header row column cannot be named `sum` -- there is no naming conflict in that context.

Comment: yes, but i think it's better practice just not to use it

Answer (score 0):

Delete quotation marks in the list eg. ‘sum’ to sum.
sum is the name of variable and ‘sum’ is a string object.
By adding the quotation marks you are saying that you want to write string ‘sum’ and ‘diff’.